# Associating a cell outside a pivot table with one within it - excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I'm currently creating a Pivot table in excel with several filters which read in rows.
What I need to do is associate a cell that sits outside of the pivot table, with the row of content within the pivot table.  So that whenever a filter is applied within the pivot table the content outside it behaves in the same way.
I don't want the values/text within the cells to change - just to follow the behaviour of the filtered content in the table.
I've  tried to add this 'outside' info to the pivot table but it just makes it over complicated.
Please can anyone help?  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

hard to answer without knowing exactly what you're trying to do however using the GETPIVOTDATA formula may achieve your desired result
(https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/GETPIVOTDATA-function-026db7b1-dd6f-4057-9396-2c2798d159db)

=GETPIVOTDATA("Value",$B$9,"Row Label","Row Value")

"Value" = the name of the field you want to return a result for

$B$9 = location of any cell in the pivot table

"Row Label" (optional, repeatable) = field that you want to filter by from row labels (if left blank will return grand total)

"Row Value" = value of filter applied to Row Label, can be a formula e.g. if row labels are in column B and you want the filter to relate to whichever value is on row 10 you can use B10

changing the values in your report filter will edit the result of this formula